# Считать данные переменную htm файла и превратить в число

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно считать переменную из HTM файла и передать её в js. Все это работает на контроллере сименс 1200.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Javascript Example</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <label id="counter">0</label>
    </body>
   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("IOCounter.htm", function(result){
                $('#counter').text(result.trim());
            });
        },1000);
        });
    </script>
 
</html>
```

Приведенный выше код читает переменную из файла .HTM, и автоматически обновляеет отображаемую величину. Файл .HTM выглядит запись ввида :="webdata".counter: которую обновляет контролер.
Как можно считать переменную которая отображается в поле

```html
<label id="counter">0</label>
```

и передать ее в java script код.

Comment: `var counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerText;`

Comment: Можно регуляркой, типо: result.match(/(?<=label id="counter"[^>]+>)[^<]+/);